# Ask Ubuntu mysterious/mispositioned "See votes, expandable usercard" overlay just started appearing on Dashboard page

Tags: bug

This overlay just started appearing, and I can't seem to get rid of it.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313434/ugly-next-privilege-text-on-user-activity-page

Comment: Easiest fix: get 25k rep >:-D

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: @MarkKirby Thank you please